# Exclude multiple words from a vector with grepl

Tags: r

Here sample data:

```
exclude.words <- c("zoznam","azet","dovera","joj","alza","telecom","google","post","sme")

main.data <- c("zoznam","registration","azet","azet.com","dovera","dna","joj","alza","telecom","google","post","sme")
```

This works if the words are equal (match exactly), however see `azet.com` that won't be excluded! For that we could use `agrepl()`.

```
main.data[!(main.data %in% exclude.words)]
```

So how to use `agrepl` with two vectors?

```
main.data[!agrepl(main.data, exclude.words)]
```

Comment: `main.data[!grepl(paste(exclude.words, collapse = "|"), main.data)]`?

Comment: yes, that's it, works. Would you expand in your answer (if you choose to submit) the meaning behind collapse=" | "? I don't understand the notion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, you can use:

```
main.data[!grepl(paste(exclude.words, collapse = "|"), main.data)]
```

to exclude any words that have a partly or complete match between the main.data and exclude.words.

```
paste(exclude.words, collapse = "|")
```

creates a single string with "|" (logical OR) between the exclude.words which can be used as a single pattern in `grepl`. Therefore, you don't need to loop over the single words.

Answer (score 1):

```
main.data[!as.logical(rowSums(sapply(exclude.words, function(x) agrepl(x, main.data))))]
# [1] "registration" "dna"


# clarification
sapply(exclude.words, function(x) agrepl(x, main.data))
#       zoznam  azet dovera   joj  alza telecom google  post   sme
#  [1,]   TRUE FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [2,]  FALSE FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [3,]  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [4,]  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [5,]  FALSE FALSE   TRUE FALSE FALSE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [6,]  FALSE FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [7,]  FALSE FALSE  FALSE  TRUE FALSE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [8,]  FALSE FALSE  FALSE FALSE  TRUE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [9,]  FALSE FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE    TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [10,]  FALSE FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE   TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [11,]  FALSE FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE  FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [12,]  FALSE FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: original approach, +1

Comment: Thanks) unfortunately it's a bit slow one

Answer (score 1):

You can use this functional programming approach:

```
library(functional)

funcs = lapply(exclude.words, function(u) function(x) x[!grepl(u, x)])

Reduce(Compose, funcs)(main.data)
#[1] "registration" "dna"
```